# Php : How to get localities based on ip address

Tags: php

I want to get localities based on IP address in Php.
I'm using geoplugin for based on IP, I got cities by using this

```
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
/*Get user ip address details with geoplugin.net*/
$geopluginURL='http://www.geoplugin.net /php.gp?ip='.$ip_address;
$addrDetailsArr =     unserialize(file_get_contents($geopluginURL)); 
/*Get City name by return array*/
$city = $addrDetailsArr['geoplugin_city']; 

/*Get Country name by return array*/

$country = $addrDetailsArr['geoplugin_countryName'];
```

Then, how to get locations of the city in selected field using this

Comment: Not clear dude, Where is the problem and what you expected?

Comment: suppose if i selected hyderabad in select field ,i want locations of that city in select dropdown, iam using geoplugin for based on ip iam getting cities

Comment: geoplugin allow you to get the location of an IP address. For dropdown, you may check this fit your requirements https://github.com/geodatasource/country-region-dropdown-menu

Comment: @Chris Lim I want city based locations

Comment: you may compile the cities information for the free IP geolocation database at https://lite.ip2location.com/database/ip-country-region-city for the display. Please take note that this database only contains those cities having IP address, i think it should be sufficient for you since you are querying the ip locality.

Comment: @ChrisLim is it work for getting all locations of the city

Comment: The LITE database shall contain all cities name that have IP assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use this [IP-Api](http://ip-api.com/docs/).
It is free. Data returned will give you the local and other details.

Comment: read here..you will need to receive the response in JSON http://ip-api.com/docs/api:json

Comment: it is getting only one location but i want all locations in that city

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is impossible to get all locations in a city. Define your 'location'. What do you mean with all locations? Is it every value of lat and lon? Or every postcode? Or every house number? Or every street? Or others?